# Фэнтези или фэнтази?

Tags: орфография

В разных источниках я встречаю написание и через Е - "фэнтези" и через А - "фэнтази". С одной стороны, через А ближе к русскому слову "фантазия", но с другой, по правилам английского языка нужно читать все-таки "фэнтези" через Е(Э). Ведь слово это английское.
Таким образом, что будет являться ошибкой: написание "фэнтези" или "фэнтази"? Стоит ли вообще в подобных словах применять правила чтения оригинального языка или лучше давать транскрипцию?

Comment: Пишите по- русски- сказка, и не ошибетесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: фэнтези

Лучшим источником для проверки является Орфографический словарь РАН под ред. Лопатина, который, в частности, представлен на сайте Грамота.ру.

Это слово вошло в состав русской лексики именно в таком виде, и только так мы обязаны его писать.

Конечно, интересно подумать, почему выбрано такая форма, но это уже будет другой вопрос. Фонетически здесь закрепился звук Э, соответствующий источнику и более удобный для произношения. Что касается графики, то, возможно, здесь буква Э противопоставлена второй гласной Е.

Fantasy

Фэнтези – заимствование путем транскрипции, а фантазия – преимущественно способом транслитерации, при этом они имеют одинаковый источник.

Answer (score 1):

[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) "Это слово вошло в состав русской лексики именно в таком виде, и только ТАК мы ОБЯЗАНЫ его писать." (Хочется встать по стойке "смирно" и крикнуть "есть, мои лингвистические вожди!!!") И это Вы мне писали, что язык нельзя регулировать? Да Вы со своим РАН - буквально диктаторы для русского языка. "Обязаны"! Это так же как и с "обеспЕчением" обязаны? Опечатка или самодурство КАКОГО-ТО чинуши в РАН ОБЯЗЫВАЕТ весь народ произносить слово не по-русски. Почему "фэнтЕзи"? Это же карикатура на слово! Произнесите его четко по буквам "фэнт-е-е-е-ези". Вот как они там придумывают вариант написания? Монетку что ли бросают? Только чтобы не "фэтАзи", как это звучит по-английски, такой что ли принцип? Там есть кто-то, кто выучил хотя бы один иностранный язык? И эти люди нас заставляют заимствовать, заимствовать американизмы. Ни иностранных языков не знают, ни родной русский не любят и не УВАЖАЮТ. Просто превращают русский язык в помойку. Без учета языковых обычаев и естественных внутренних законов.